# custom Child layout of Expandable listview android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I using `ExpandableListview` ... I am able to set the values retrieved from web service to single  `Textview` of child layout .
Now need to set values  two different `Textviews` in child layout from web service
I am able to work with single textviews , but not have enough idea to work with two `Textview`

MainActivity.java

```
if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        cat = jsonObj.getJSONArray(All_link.TAG_NEWS);

                        String err = jsonObj.getString(All_link.TAG_ERROR);
                        Log.e("------>Error", String.valueOf(err));

                        if (err.equals("1")) {

                        } else {

                            // Adding child data
                            listDataHeader.add("Home");
                            listDataHeader.add("News Category");
                            listDataHeader.add("");
                            listDataHeader.add("My Favourites");
                            listDataHeader.add("Story-Photo-Video");
                            listDataHeader.add("About Us");
                            listDataHeader.add("Rate this App");
                            listDataHeader.add("Share this App");
                            listDataHeader.add("Settings");



                            // looping through All Contacts
                            for (int i = 0; i < cat.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = cat.getJSONObject(i);

                                String cat_id = c.getString(All_link.TAG_CAT_ID);
                                String cat_name = c
                                        .getString(All_link.TAG_CAT_NAME);
                                String image_icon = c.getString("image_icon");

                                /*navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(cat_name,
                                        image_icon, navMenuIcons.getResourceId(
                                                1, -1), true
                                                ,"1",id));*/


                                list_items.add(cat_name);                                                                                           

                                Log.e("list_items", "karlist "+list_items);
                            }
                            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), new ArrayList<String>()); // No child
                            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), list_items); // With child                         
                            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), new ArrayList<String>()); // No child
                            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), new ArrayList<String>()); // No child
                            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), new ArrayList<String>()); // No child
                            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(5), new ArrayList<String>()); // No child
                            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(6), new ArrayList<String>()); // No child
                            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(7), new ArrayList<String>()); // No child
                            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(8), new ArrayList<String>()); // No child
```

ExpandableListAdapter.java

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private static final int[] EMPTY_STATE_SET = {};
    private static final int[] GROUP_EXPANDED_STATE_SET =
            {android.R.attr.state_expanded};
    private static final int[][] GROUP_STATE_SETS = {
        EMPTY_STATE_SET, // 0
        GROUP_EXPANDED_STATE_SET // 1
    };
    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        TextView txtListChild_id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_id);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        Log.e("groupPosition", "kargr "+groupPosition);

            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .size();


    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);              

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        View ind = convertView.findViewById( R.id.explist_indicator);
        if( ind != null ) {
            ImageView indicator = (ImageView)ind;
            if( getChildrenCount( groupPosition ) == 0 ) {
                indicator.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
            } else {
                indicator.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                int stateSetIndex = ( isExpanded ? 1 : 0) ;
                Drawable drawable = indicator.getDrawable();
                drawable.setState(GROUP_STATE_SETS[stateSetIndex]);
            }
        }


        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You use *drawer_list_item* as xml resource for your child layout, so you can add another TextView on drawer_list_item.xml and set the value of this text in getChildView() method (like you do for *txtListChild*)

Comment: yes ..I done that .. but didn't know how to use passed value in adapter .

Comment: want to send cat_id with cat_name and use it in adapter

Comment: the same thing for cat_id same and cat_name you just add  2 other text. to get your data you must crete a method that returns the listDadaChild object (you use an ArrayList<String> i guess), and from this object you call all the data that you have stored and put it on TextViews

Comment: sorry to say this .. a sample code would be more helpful ... HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild .....List<String> list_cat_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Class to handle your child data :

```
public class YourData {
    public  String cat_name;
    public  String cat_id;


        public YourData(String id, String name) {
            cat_id= id;
            cat_name = name;
        }

    }
```

Now your child list will look like :

```
private List<YourData> _listDataHeader; // header titles
```

You can fill this List as :

```
_listDataHeader.add(new YourData(id,name));
```

Change the adapter signature to  :

```
 public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<YourData>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }
```

And use it in GetView as :

```
 @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final YourData childText = (YourData) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        ....
        txtListChild.setText(childText.cat_name);
        txtListChild_id.setText(childText.cat_id);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: I wanna set cat_id and cat_name to HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild ..how to do that

Comment: the code u suggested is disturbing my listDataHeader.add("Home");
             listDataHeader.add("News Category");
             listDataHeader.add("");
             listDataHeader.add("My Favourites");
             listDataHeader.add("Story-Photo-Video");
             listDataHeader.add("About Us");
             listDataHeader.add("Rate this App");
             listDataHeader.add("Share this App");
             listDataHeader.add("Settings");

Comment: You need to change that.. i have given example..take it as `HashMap<String, List<YourData>> listDataChild`

Comment: Thanks for ur help ... I managed to store the data with SharedPrefrence